# Disk operations in windows 7 are slow

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

My computer started lagging last Sunday. I tried to reboot it and it failed.
Trying to boot into failsafe mode takes around two hours. It mainly freezes on two files: scsiport.sys and classpnp.sys
When it finally has started all disc operations are really slow. When it has run for a while it goes faster, probably due to data moved into RAM instead.
It froze on an other file before that was associated with Avast but uninstalling it didn't really help.
A critical windows update was installed on Sunday but rolling back the update didn't help. 
I had a guess about the sound card but disabling the sound card drivers also didn’t help.

I have an inkling of an idea that it might be Intel rapid storage technology that might be acting up but it doesn't allow me to reinstall it from failsafe mode and I haven't been able to log into normal mode for a while.
I would appreciate suggestions regarding how to get into normal mode again and/or what can be the root cause.

Comment: I would get on, install a SMART tool and check the hard drive life. Boot into safe mode, and then go to MSCONFIG, disable everything you can and see if this then lets you load up normally. Or, take your hard drive out, slave it in another machine and then run the smart tool just to rule out the HDD. Either way, doing this will allow you to (hopefully) take a back up!

Comment: Seems like you where right. My first checks with SMART didn't tell me that anything was wrong. Using a livecd painted a different picture.

Comment: The disc where windows resides is borked. Luckily that disc and both it's partitions is just programs with no personal data (plus I got backup of the personal stuff). Now just a question to get a new disc. Thanks for the help. If you add your answer as an "real" answer I can give you a bit more credit @DaveRook :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get on, install a SMART tool and check the hard drive life. Boot into safe mode, and then go to MSCONFIG, disable everything you can and see if this then lets you load up normally. Or, take your hard drive out, slave it in another machine and then run the smart tool just to rule out the HDD. Either way, doing this will allow you to (hopefully) take a back up!